# How to post two (several) arguments via requests.post() in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to post **two arguments**: **.xls file**, and one more **constant** (e.g. 1000)

this is how I tried to do it, but it failed:
`requests.post('http://13.59.5.143:8082/blablabla', 'data.xls', 1000)`

I also tried this, and it doesn`t work too:

- `requests.post('http://13.59.5.143:8082/blablabla', ['data.xls', 1000])`
- `requests.post('http://13.59.5.143:8082/blablabla', {'file':'data.xls' ; 'store_id':1000)`

**What is the right way to post 2 arguments using Python requests lib?**

If not requests lib, what are other possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

payload = {'file':'data.xls', 'store_id':1000}
r = requests.get('http://13.59.5.143:8082/blablabla', params=payload)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Watch-out for down-voters if you don't provide context (from which we can learn).

Comment: i fixed a syntax error, look at the wrong bracker ] in {'file':'data.xls' ; 'store_id':1000])